# Optimization function to minimize certain geometric statistics

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization, area

I have geometric regions like below. The regions shapes are irregular. But here for convenience, I have drawn simple shapes:

[image: Region]

## Known statistics

I know these parameters:

- The total count of regions.
- The area for each region.

  - Hence I know the total area too.

## Question

I have a range of **choices** available for the above regions.

The objective is to:

- Minimize the total area of the regions.
- Minimize the total count of the regions.

It means, the optimized case is a case which has lower cumulative area and lower number of scattered regions.

I cannot figure out how to come up with a *cost* or *optimization* function to help me choose from available **choices**. Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks.

Comment: 1) In fact, the word **choices** could be replaced by "algorithmic steps" ... 2) Second question, can you superimpose your shapes as if they were pieces of paper ?

Comment: @JeanMarie The answer to 1st question is *no*. By **choices** I don't mean *algorithm steps*. It means, there are actual different choices coming from real world scenarios.

Comment: @JeanMarie The answer to 2nd question is *yes*. I have the shapes coordinates. So I can superimpose them like pieces of paper. It would take some mathematical/programming effort of course.

Comment: Frankly I don't understand, and I must not be alone because you haven't had other comments than mine...

Comment: @JeanMarie Right. I may close this question and prepare one which is more clear :) Thanks.

Comment: Could you give a simple example with 2 or 3 shapes for example a rectangle and 2 circles and what is the final geometric objective, for example obtain by superimposition the shape of a stadium or something like that ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Alright, it makes sense. I'm going to prepare a simple & clear example.